# NotifyOfPropertyChange not triggered in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I've created a WPF project for the express purpose of illustrating my project.

Disclaimer: I am using Caliburn.Micro ONLY for using `PropertyChangedBase` and `BindableCollection`. Everything else here in this project is boilerplate WPF stuff.

Right, so, I have a class `DataItem`. It has got just two properties:

- an `int` called `Qty`, and
- a calculated property called `Sum`, which
  is double of `Qty`.

That's it. For the sake of clarity, here's the code:

```
public class DataLine : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private int qty;

    public int Qty
    {
        get
        {
            return qty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == qty)
            {
                return;
            }

            qty = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Sum);
        }
    }

    public int Sum => qty * 2;

    public DataLine(int a)
    {
        Qty = a;            
    }
}
```

Now, the ViewModel. It's got

- a `BindableCollection` (which is Caliburn's flavour of `ObservableCollection`) of `DataLine`,
- an `int` which will add up all the `Sum` of `DataLines`, and
- an ICommand.

The ICommand does nothing but trigger `NotifyPropertyChanged` for the `BindableCollection` and `int`.

Here's the code:

```
class ViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new BindableCollection<DataLine>
        {
            new DataLine(1),
            new DataLine(2),
            new DataLine(4),
            new DataLine(6)
        };

        RefreshCommand = new RefreshCommand(this);
    }

    private BindableCollection<DataLine> _data;

    public BindableCollection<DataLine> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == _data)
            {
                return;
            }

            _data = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Amount);
        }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }

    public void RefreshAction()
    {
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Amount);
    }

    public int? Amount => Data?.Sum(c => c.Sum);

}
```

Now, for the `View`:
It's very simple.

- There's a `DataGrid`, bound to the `BindableCollection`.
- There's a `Button`, bound to the `ICommand`.
- There's a 'TextBox`, bound to`Amount`.

Here's the body of the `View`:

```
<DockPanel>        
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Amount, TargetNullValue='', Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Content="Refresh"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</DockPanel>
```

When I run it, I get something like this:

[image: Initial Window]

Now comes the tricky part - let me just edit one of the rows.

[image: Edited]

For sake of clarity, I have added an arrow to show where my cursor was after editing the `DataGrid`. Check how the `Sum` of first row is updated, but the `Amount` at the bottom of the screen remains the same.

Now, when I click `Refresh`, this happens:

[image: The Updated View]

The `Amount` is now updated properly.

All of which finally brings me to my question: What's wrong with `DataGrid`? Why is `DataGrid` not triggering its setter when the rows are edited? And how can I make sure it is triggered?

Comment: Are you expecting that changing a property of an object in a BindableCollection also magically changes the collection property itself? Your Data setter isn't called just because you edit a collection element. So, "what's wrong with DataGrid"? Nothing, it's just your wrong expectation.

Comment: Is there any way to raise `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` on the collection itself when any of its child objects are edited?

Comment: Sure, DataLine could somehow have access to the parent view model, and call a method that does `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Amount)`

Comment: But that'd tightly couple the `DataLine` with `ViewModel`. Can BindableCollection be modified in a way where it raises its own `PropertyChanged()` event when any of its child item raises `PropertyChanged()`?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Datagrids and updating meta/aggregate data irritating at times. 
Currently i would agree with Clemens that i am not sure you can easily change a BindableCollection to suit your needs.

However, a quick solution to not create a tight couple between your `DataLine` and `ViewModel` is using a passable Action. You could always get fancy with some abstraction or generics. But I created a simple edit of your code to show what i mean.

Essentially you create a mechanism such that a `ViewModel` can pass an Action to an Object. If I were implementing this, I would probably implement some form of Interface or Generic that stops me from having to add an Action Method to each Model. Or at least inherit from a class that has the Notify Action. For clarity and easy reading, ill just do a simple edit.

In Your DataLine add:

`//NotifyOfPropertyChange();
 //NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Sum);
 NotifyFromParent?.Invoke();`

to your `Qty` setter, and:

```
   public DataLine(int a, System.Action action = null)
   {
     Qty = a;
     NotifyFromParent = action;
   }

   public System.Action NotifyFromParent;
```

then in your ViewModel you can go:

```
Data = new BindableCollection<DataLine>
{
   new DataLine(1, () => RefreshAction()),
   new DataLine(2, () => RefreshAction()),
   new DataLine(4, () => RefreshAction()),
   new DataLine(6, () => RefreshAction())
};
```

Like i said, you could make this much fancier. As far as i have experienced you need to create a mechanism to update aggregate or external data when editing cells in a datagrid, and you desire the update to immediately following said edit.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. I made a base class of `ObjectWithNotifyParent` which has the `Action` and a base `ctor`. This would be used for any object of which `BindableCollection` is made. Thanks for this.